# I have a ged file with 44k entries - what is a good program which will handle it?

Tags: gedcom, software-recommendations

I began using the free software, Simple Family Tree, to enter my information.  Three years later, I have over 44,000 people entered.   The program crashes all the time.  Can anyone recommend a good genealogy program that will accommodate such a large file?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  Thank you for having taken the [Tour] which leads to the [help] that says `If your question is ... not about ... Which genealogy software or website is “the best” ... then you’re in the right place.`  For questions seeking software recommendations like this one the place to ask is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange or it could also be asked in our [Roots chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6003/roots) but to post there you will need to earn 20 reputation points first here first. To help you participate there I have upvoted your question.

Comment: The article [What Can You Do With the World's Largest Family Tree?](https://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2017/02/family-tree-genealogy-research/516819/) suggests that a tree of 20 million people has been created by Ancestry.com and one of 13 million by Geni.com.

Comment: Family Historian will cope with this without issue and uses the Gedcom file format. There is a 30 day free trial that you can check out it is fully functional you just cannot run any plugins.

Comment: I think it is really damn good question, because (a) it is related to the genealogy itself and (b) not every program can handle such a big trees. More - such a requirement for good program is a must.

Comment: @GeorgeGaál So maybe someone should vote to re-open this question.  It looks on topic to me.  It is not asking for the "best" software, rather asking for ones that can handle large numbers of people.  I use Kith and Kin http://kithkinpro.spansoft.org/, and that handles large numbers "Almost unlimited storage. 2,100 million of any one record type in any tree."